# How can I add all the images in a directory to a word document using Python

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32

I have been trying to make this code work so I can add hundreds of pictures into a microsoft word document but can't quite get it to work. I think the problem is in defining the location of the images correctly.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

#creating a word application object
wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application') #create a word application object
wordApp.Visible = True # hide the word application
doc = wordApp.Documents.Add() # create a new application

#Formating the document
doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 20
doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 20
doc.PageSetup.Orientation = win32.constants.wdOrientLandscape
# a4 paper size: 595x842
doc.PageSetup.PageWidth = 595
doc.PageSetup.PageHeight = 842
header_range= doc.Sections(1).Headers(win32.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
header_range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = win32.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
header_range.Font.Bold = True
header_range.Font.Size = 20
header_range.Text = "Header Of The Document"

# Inserting Tables

total_column = 2
total_row = 5
rng = doc.Range(0,0)
rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = win32.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
table = doc.Tables.Add(rng,total_row, total_column)
table.Borders.Enable = False
if total_column > 1:
    table.Columns.DistributeWidth()

#Collecting images in the same directory and inserting them into the document
frame_max_width= 167 # the maximum width of a picture
frame_max_height= 125 # the maximum height of a picture

filenames = os.listdir("some_directory")  #Do I need this? I think it might be the issue...

for index, filename in enumerate(filenames): # loop through all the files and folders for adding pictures
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), filename)): # check whether the current object is a file or not
        if filename[len(filename)-3: len(filename)].upper() == 'JPG': # check whether the current object is a JPG file

            #calculating the position of each image to be put into the correct table cell
            cell_column= index % total_column + 1
            cell_row = index / total_column + 1
            print 'cell_column=%s,cell_row=%s' % (cell_column,cell_row)

            #we are formatting the style of each cell
            cell_range= table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = win32.constants.wdLineSpaceSingle
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0 
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3

            #this is where we are going to insert the images
            current_pic = cell_range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), filename))
            width, height = (frame_max_height*width/height, frame_max_height)

            #changing the size of each image to fit the table cell
            current_pic.Height= height
            current_pic.Width= width

            #putting a name underneath each image which can be handy
            table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range.InsertAfter("\n"+filename)
```

this code gets me my doc created and one image inserted but then I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pic_dump.py", line 56, in 
    width, height = (frame_max_height*width/height, frame_max_height)
NameError: name 'width' is not defined.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, massive thanks to Mr. Me, I now have this working as I want. The working code is as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

#creating a word application object
wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application') #create a word application object
wordApp.Visible = True # hide the word application
doc = wordApp.Documents.Add() # create a new application

#Formating the document
doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 20
doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 20
doc.PageSetup.Orientation = win32.constants.wdOrientLandscape
# a4 paper size: 595x842
doc.PageSetup.PageWidth = 595
doc.PageSetup.PageHeight = 842


# Inserting Tables
my_dir="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"
filenames = os.listdir(my_dir)
piccount=0
file_count = 0
for i in filenames:
    if i[len(i)-3: len(i)].upper() == 'JPG': # check whether the current object is a JPG file
        piccount = piccount + 1
        #file_count= file_count + 1
print piccount, " images will be inserted"
#print filenames
total_column = 2
total_row = int(piccount/total_column)+2
rng = doc.Range(0,0)
rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = win32.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
table = doc.Tables.Add(rng,total_row, total_column)
table.Borders.Enable = False
if total_column > 1:
    table.Columns.DistributeWidth()

#Collecting images in the same directory and inserting them into the document
frame_max_width= 167 # the maximum width of a picture
frame_max_height= 125 # the maximum height of a picture


piccount = 1

for index, filename in enumerate(filenames): # loop through all the files and folders for adding pictures
    #if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), filename)):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(my_dir), filename)): # check whether the current object is a file or not
        if filename[len(filename)-3: len(filename)].upper() == 'JPG': # check whether the current object is a JPG file
            piccount = piccount + 1
            print filename, len(filename), filename[len(filename)-3: len(filename)].upper()


            cell_column = (piccount % total_column + 1) #calculating the position of each image to be put into the correct table cell
            cell_row = (piccount/total_column + 1)
            print 'cell_column=%s,cell_row=%s' % (cell_column,cell_row)

            #we are formatting the style of each cell
            cell_range= table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = win32.constants.wdLineSpaceSingle
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3

            #this is where we are going to insert the images
            current_pic = cell_range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(my_dir), filename))
            width, height = (frame_max_height*frame_max_width/frame_max_height, frame_max_height)

            #changing the size of each image to fit the table cell
            current_pic.Height= height
            current_pic.Width= width

            #putting a name underneath each image which can be handy
            table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range.InsertAfter("\n"+filename)
        else: continue
```

Comment: This is awesome! If I change the table to have 3 columns how to do I get the first photo to insert in column 1 not 3?

Comment: Change piccount = 1 to piccount = -1
Also this line can be added to give proper figure captions
`current_pic.Range.InsertCaption(Label="Figure", Title=": "+filename[:len(filename)-4]+"\n\n\n")`
which replaces the penultimate line

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a python version issue (I'm not that good), but I had to add parentheses to the "print" calls.  After that, it works like a dream.  Just an fyi/helpful note.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line. `width, height = (frame_max_height*width/height, frame_max_height)`.

You're setting the `width` = `frame_max_height*width/height`, but it is impossible for python to times `frame_max_height` * `width` when you haven't told Python what `width` is. You need to set `width` equal to some value first to resolve this error.

Comment: So I tested this with the sample pictures that come pre-installed with windows and it works perfectly but I cant get it to work with any other .jpg files... @ Mr. Me

Comment: For some reason they are not being recognised as .jpg files when I add a "print filename" command to see what is making it through the image collection process they don't show up...

Comment: Try placing the pictures in the same location as the default ones, and see if that works. That way we know it's nothing to do with the pictures, but the way the program is looking for them. I would split the line `filenames = os.listdir("some_directory")` into two line `my_dir = 'some_directory'` and `filenames = os.listdir(my_dir)` I would then replace the line `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), filename)):` with `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(my_dir), filename)):`...

Comment: ...Right now it is checking if the file exists at wherever the current working directory is. `os.path.abspath(".")` will give you the current working directory, instead we want the directory of the jpg files, so that is why I would replace `os.path.abspath(".")` with `os.path.abspath(my_dir)`